# Fatal error in Ghostscript when processing multiple files

Tags: python, ghostscript

Python 3.7.5

OS: Windows Server 2016

Ghostscript version: 9.5

I am trying to do text extraction using Ghostscript for multiple PDFs in a directory. The directory currently contains 2 PDFs: 1234.pdf and 5678.pdf.

```
import os
import sys

def pdf2txt(directory,file):
    import locale
    import ghostscript
    args=[file,"-dBATCH","-dNOPAUSE","-dNOPROMPT","-sDEVICE=txtwrite","-sOutputFile="+directory+"\\output\\"+file+"-%d.txt",directory+"\\"+file]
    encoding=locale.getpreferredencoding()
    args=[a.encode(encoding) for a in args]
    print (args)
    ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)

directory=sys.argv[1]

files=os.listdir(directory)
for file in files:
    print("Trying "+directory+"\\"+file)
    pdf2txt(directory,file)
```

The issue I am having is that the first PDF gets processed without a problem, but trying to process the second PDF always causes Python to barf. I've noticed that I get this error even when doing text extraction from the Python console. The only way I can extract a second file is to quit Python and start it back up.

I've renamed the files so the second PDF gets processed first. That PDF gets processed without issue, and the now second PDF which was processed successfully before now throws a fatal error. I've tried resetting my args list and encoding variable back to nothing, invoking methods in ghostscript that don't exist, such as .quit() or .exit(). I did see a post that mentioned that the exit method was commented out in *init*, which it was. I took the comment out, but no success.

```
C:\Users\bob\Documents>python exporter.py c:\users\bob\Desktop\PDFs
Trying c:\users\bob\Desktop\PDFs\1234.pdf
[b'1234.pdf', b'-dBATCH', b'-dNOPAUSE', b'-dNOPROMPT', b'-sDEVICE=txtwrite', b'-sOutputFile=c:\\users\\bob\\Desktop\\PDFs\\output\\1234.pdf-%d.txt', b'c:\\users\\bob\\Desktop\\PDFs\\1234.pdf']
GPL Ghostscript 9.50 (2019-10-15)
Copyright (C) 2019 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 22.
Page 1
Page 2
Page 3
Page 4
Trying c:\users\bob\Desktop\PDFs\5678.pdf
[b'5678.pdf', b'-dBATCH', b'-dNOPAUSE', b'-dNOPROMPT', b'-sDEVICE=txtwrite', b'-sOutputFile=c:\\users\\bob\\Desktop\\PDFs\\output\\5678.pdf-%d.txt', b'c:\\users\\bob\\Desktop\\PDFs\\5678.pdf']
GPL Ghostscript 9.50 (2019-10-15)
Copyright (C) 2019 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exporter.py", line 18, in <module>
    pdf2txt(directory,file)
  File "exporter.py", line 11, in pdf2txt
    ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\ghostscript\__init__.py", line 174, in Ghostscript
    stderr=kw.get('stderr', None))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\ghostscript\__init__.py", line 74, in __init__
    rc = gs.init_with_args(instance, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\ghostscript\_gsprint.py", line 273, in init_with_args
    raise GhostscriptError(rc)
ghostscript._gsprint.GhostscriptError: Fatal
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue today and found that `ghostscript.Ghostscript` is supposed to be called in `with` block. Plus, before creating a new instance of `ghostscript.Ghostscript`, I have to call `ghostscript.cleanup()`.

Try this:

```py
import os
import sys

def pdf2txt(directory,file):
    import locale
    import ghostscript
    args=[file,"-dBATCH","-dNOPAUSE","-dNOPROMPT","-sDEVICE=txtwrite","-sOutputFile="+directory+"\\output\\"+file+"-%d.txt",directory+"\\"+file]
    encoding=locale.getpreferredencoding()
    args=[a.encode(encoding) for a in args]
    print (args)
    with ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args) as g:
        ghostscript.cleanup()

directory=sys.argv[1]

files=os.listdir(directory)
for file in files:
    print("Trying "+directory+"\\"+file)
    pdf2txt(directory,file)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me nuts, but it seems you can't have the same input and output name.

```
args = b"""gs -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -sOutputFile=a.tif dummy.pdf -c""".split()
ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)
```

This works (input = dummy.pdf, output = a.tif)

This (input = dummy.pdf, output = dummy.tif):

```
args = b"""gs -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -sOutputFile=dummy.tif dummy.pdf -c""".split()
ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)
```

in the first instance produces an error which says:

> GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: **** Could not open the file dummy.tif .

and if I try it again, the error changes:

```
Exception ignored in: <function Ghostscript.__del__ at 0x7f86c4091f30>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ghostscript/__init__.py", line 125, in __del__
    self.exit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ghostscript/__init__.py", line 128, in exit
    if self._instance:
AttributeError: 'Ghostscript' object has no attribute '_instance'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ghostscript/__init__.py", line 76, in __init__
    self._instance = gs.new_instance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ghostscript/_gsprint.py", line 172, in new_instance
    raise GhostscriptError(rc)
ghostscript._gsprint.GhostscriptError: Fatal
```

Changing the output file's name (dummy -> something_else) fixed it for me. However, this is a workaround - if anyone has better advice please let me know (I've just started using ghostscript, so may have missed something).